# I want to make a search form where I can search specifically for entities with a null relationship to another entity on Symfony 5

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony5

I am writing a symfony app where some entity (let's say a car) has a relationship to another entity (let's say a paint color), but the relationship can also be null (a car without any color documented).

I'd like to make a form to search for cars in my database where you can either :

- search a car with a specific color (yellow for example)
- search for a car without any color documented
- not search anything in that field (for example, I don't care for the car's color, all I want to search is the amount of doors the car has)

I can easily do 1 and 3, but 2 is more difficult.

Best I could do was to load all colors from the database, hack inside an unpersisted color entity (which would have a null id) and put it in a choicetype.

However this never felt "clean" and I now have a problem with that.

Here's my form so far :

```
class Search extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    private function getColorRepository(): ColorRepository
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository(Color::class);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $colors = $this->getColorRepository->findAll();
        $unidentifiedColor = new Color();
        $unidentifiedColor->setName("Not identified");
        array_unshift($colors, $unidentifiedColor);

        $builder
        ->add('color', ChoiceType::class, [

            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $colors,
            'placeholder' => 'Select a color ...',
        ]);
    }
}
```

This made what I expected (Default choice is a placeholder, second choice is "Not identified" and the rest is the colors you can pick). But I need to use the EntityType now, and I can't do this anymore.

Did anyone face this problem ? How would you fix this issue ?

Comment: I’m really confused by your usage of “null relationship”. If you don’t have data, just don’t search on it. The relationship isn’t “null”, it just doesn’t exist. (True, in the entity it might be null or an empty collection, but that’s PHP.) You might have to tweak the query, but if color is empty, just don’t query on the color then, unless I’m missing something?

Comment: Yes sometimes the information doesn't exist. The relationship between a car and its color is ManyToOne, so a car with no color will have a null value in the database. As for searching for a car with no color, this is a valid search for some people, because the database was made a long time before this symfony app and sometimes this kind of information was missing. However users may have the missing information, so searching for cars that have no data in this field makes sense, because that's what the user is looking for : a car that is missing some data so they can complete it.